# How to print the command before it executes?

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

I need to run some commands like mentioned below and it should be display on screen before it execute and then output of the command

```
lsuser -f root|grep -i maxage|awk -F= '{print$2}'
```

Returns 13.

I tried like storing command in variable as below, but it didn't work.

```
mxage="lsuser -f root|grep -i maxage|awk -F= '{print$2}'"
echo "$maxage"
echo "`$maxage`"
```

**output should be like:**

`lsuser -f root|grep -i maxage|awk -F= '{print$2}'
 13`

Comment: you want to run _what_ before _what_ ?

Comment: Sorry [I closed as a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41876885/revisions). I just focused on the last part of the question, while the ultimate goal here is clearly different. Thanks @chepner for undoing it.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend simply using `set -x`, which logs commands to standard error before they are executed. You can disable this after you are done with `set +x`.

```
set -x 
lsuser -f root|grep -i maxage|awk -F= '{print$2}'
set +x
```

Drawbacks:

1. The data is written to standard error, not standard output. (In newer versions of `bash`, though, you can specify an arbitrary file descriptor by setting `BASH_XTRACEFD`.)
2. The execution of `set +x` is traced as well.

---

If you set the value of the variable *very* carefully, you can use `eval`.

```
cmd="lsuser -f root|grep -i maxage|awk -F= '{print\$2}'"
echo "$cmd"
eval "$cmd"
```

However, I do not recommend this approach. It is, in theory, possible to correctly set the value of `cmd` so that it both logs accurately and executes correctly and as intended, but I find it to be more trouble than it is worth. (However, I wait for someone to show how to do it easily; I know it involves `printf` and the `%q` specifier.)

Answer (score 0):

`set -x` is good for debugging a script. When you just want to see your original command, use

```
set -v
lsuser -f root|grep -i maxage|awk -F= '{print$2}'
set +v
```